# Question about 4-bit binary adder on 7 segment display and subtraction

Tags: adder

In my lab, we successfully built a 4-bit binary parallel adder and were able to display the results of some tests on the 7 segment display.

But our TA asked us to try something: subtract 1-9, and we got 7. Why is that?

Comment: how did you do the subtraction? How are we supposed to know what's wrong if you don't explain that?

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong at all: that was that TA's point. He said we were meant to get 7 on the display (even though 1-9 doesn't equal 7), but instead of telling us why, he suggested that we think about it on our own, and I haven't figured it out.

Comment: hint: integer wrapping

Comment: was it 1 or 10h-9h=7h  (hex)

Comment: Wondering how, exactly, you implemented a subtraction with an adder...

Comment: Did you XOR inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically whenever you do 1-9 in binary that looks like

00001 (1) - 01001(9)

however since most of the subtraction is done by twos complement it is actually

*00001 + 10110 =>  10111*

Your display will only display the bottom four bits which are 0111, which is seven.

Cheers!

Comment: OP's system is 4-bit. Yours seems to be truncated 5-bit. Can you explain?

Comment: I think that would depend on how the adder was made and implemented, as well as how was the subtraction performed. From my labs we did "adder implementations" in some sort of HDL with fpga's tied to them that could be a case, I really don't know how you would subtract -9 in a 4 bit implementation

Comment: @Transistor if you do what he did, for 4 bits, still the system only shows 0111 which is still 7.

Answer (score 0):

in binary:

```
1: 0001
```

Subtracting 9 times 1:

```
0000 (-1)
1111 (-2)
1110 (-3)
1101 (-4)
1100 (-5)
1011 (-6)
1010 (-7)
1001 (-8)
1000 (-9)
```

I would expect 1000, which is 8.